# Kibana: searching for a specific phrase, returns without results, while another search returns the phrase

Tags: logstash, kibana, kibana-4

Looks like a simple usecase but for some reason I just can't figure out how to do this, or google a clear example.

Lets say I have a message stored in logstash
message:

> "info: 2015-11-28 22:02:19,232:common:INFO:ENV: Production
>   User:None:Username:None:LOG: publishing to bus "

And I want to search in kibana (version 4) for the phrase:"publishing to bus"
I'll get a set of results
But if I'll search for: "None:LOG: publishing to bus"
Then I get "No results found".

While Obviously this phrase does exists and is returned by the previous search.

So my question is basically - What is going on? What is the correct way to search for a possible long phrase and why does the second example fail.

**EDIT:**
The stored JSON.

```
{
  "_index": "logz-ngdxrkmolklnvngumaitximbohqwbocg-151206_v1",
  "_type": "django_logger",
  "_id": "AVF2DPxZZst_8_8_m-se",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "log": " publishing to bus {'user_id': 8866, 'event_id': 'aibRBPcLxcAzsEVRtFZVU5', 'timestamp': 1449384441, 'quotes': {}, 'rates': {u'EURUSD': Decimal('1.061025'), u'GBPUSD': Decimal('1.494125'), u'EURGBP': Decimal('0.710150')}, 'event': 'AccountInstrumentsUpdated', 'minute': 1449384420}",
    "logger": "common",
    "log_level": "INFO",
    "message": "2015-12-06 06:47:21,298:common:INFO:ENV: Production User:None:Username:None:LOG: publishing to bus {'user_id': 8866, 'event_id': 'aibRBPcLxcAzsEVRtFZVU5', 'timestamp': 1449384441, 'quotes': {}, 'rates': {u'EURUSD': Decimal('1.061025'), u'GBPUSD': Decimal('1.494125'), u'EURGBP': Decimal('0.710150')}, 'event': 'AccountInstrumentsUpdated', 'minute': 1449384420}",
    "type": "django_logger",
    "tags": [
      "celery"
    ],
    "path": "//path/to/logs/out.log",
    "environment": "Staging",
    "@timestamp": "2015-12-06T06:47:21.298+00:00",
    "user_id": "None",
    "host": "path.to.host",
    "timestamp": "2015-12-06 06:47:21,298",
    "username": "None"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      1449384441298
    ]
  },
  "highlight": {
    "message": [
      "2015-12-06 06:47:21,298:common:INFO:ENV: Staging User:None:Username:None:LOG: @kibana-highlighted-field@publishing@/kibana-highlighted-field@ @kibana-highlighted-field@to@/kibana-highlighted-field@ @kibana-highlighted-field@bus@/kibana-highlighted-field@ {'user_id': **, 'event_id': 'aibRBPcLxcAzsEVRtFZVU5', 'timestamp': 1449384441, 'quotes': {}, 'rates': {u'EURUSD': Decimal('1.061025'), u'GBPUSD': Decimal('1.494125'), u'EURGBP': Decimal('0.710150')}, 'event': 'AccountInstrumentsUpdated', 'minute': 1449384420}"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1449384441298
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried: "none:log: publishing to bus" ?

Comment: Tried now. doesn't return any result

Comment: I belive `:` is a special character, try escaping it:`\:`

Comment: @xjedam Nope.. tried it. Doesn't help

Comment: What does your mapping look like for this field?

Comment: It's not clear from the context, but are you actually surrounding your input string in Kibana with double quotes or not? Do you mind showing the `query_string` part of the query that Kibana sends? (see [here](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1370#issuecomment-108676390) on how to see the request.)

Answer (score 1):

Accodrding to Elasticsearch, it uses **standard analyzer** as default. The standard analyzer tokenizes the message field as follows:

> "2015-12-06 06:47:21,298:common:INFO:ENV: Production
>   User:None:Username:None:LOG: publishing to bus {'user_id': 8866,
>   'event_id': 'aibRBPcLxcAzsEVRtFZVU5', 'timestamp': 1449384441,
>   'quotes': {}, 'rates': {u'EURUSD': Decimal('1.061025'), u'GBPUSD':
>   Decimal('1.494125'), u'EURGBP': Decimal('0.710150')}, 'event':
>   'AccountInstrumentsUpdated', 'minute': 1449384420}"

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "2015",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 4,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "12",
      "start_offset": 5,
      "end_offset": 7,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "06",
      "start_offset": 8,
      "end_offset": 10,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "06",
      "start_offset": 11,
      "end_offset": 13,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 3
    },
    {
      "token": "47",
      "start_offset": 14,
      "end_offset": 16,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 4
    },
    {
      "token": "21,298",
      "start_offset": 17,
      "end_offset": 23,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 5
    },
    {
      "token": "common:info:env",
      "start_offset": 24,
      "end_offset": 39,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 6
    },
    {
      "token": "production",
      "start_offset": 41,
      "end_offset": 51,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 7
    },
    {
      "token": "user:none:username:none:log",
      "start_offset": 52,
      "end_offset": 79,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 8
    },
    {
      "token": "publishing",
      "start_offset": 81,
      "end_offset": 91,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 9
    },
    {
      "token": "to",
      "start_offset": 92,
      "end_offset": 94,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 10
    },
    {
      "token": "bus",
      "start_offset": 95,
      "end_offset": 98,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 11
    },
    {
      "token": "user_id",
      "start_offset": 100,
      "end_offset": 107,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 12
    },
    {
      "token": "8866",
      "start_offset": 109,
      "end_offset": 113,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 13
    },
    {
      "token": "event_id",
      "start_offset": 115,
      "end_offset": 123,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 14
    },
    {
      "token": "aibrbpclxcazsevrtfzvu5",
      "start_offset": 125,
      "end_offset": 147,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 15
    },
    {
      "token": "timestamp",
      "start_offset": 149,
      "end_offset": 158,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 16
    },
    {
      "token": "1449384441",
      "start_offset": 160,
      "end_offset": 170,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 17
    },
    {
      "token": "quotes",
      "start_offset": 172,
      "end_offset": 178,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 18
    },
    {
      "token": "rates",
      "start_offset": 184,
      "end_offset": 189,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 19
    },
    {
      "token": "ueurusd",
      "start_offset": 192,
      "end_offset": 199,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 20
    },
    {
      "token": "decimal",
      "start_offset": 201,
      "end_offset": 208,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 21
    },
    {
      "token": "1.061025",
      "start_offset": 209,
      "end_offset": 217,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 22
    },
    {
      "token": "ugbpusd",
      "start_offset": 220,
      "end_offset": 227,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 23
    },
    {
      "token": "decimal",
      "start_offset": 229,
      "end_offset": 236,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 24
    },
    {
      "token": "1.494125",
      "start_offset": 237,
      "end_offset": 245,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 25
    },
    {
      "token": "ueurgbp",
      "start_offset": 248,
      "end_offset": 255,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 26
    },
    {
      "token": "decimal",
      "start_offset": 257,
      "end_offset": 264,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 27
    },
    {
      "token": "0.710150",
      "start_offset": 265,
      "end_offset": 273,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 28
    },
    {
      "token": "event",
      "start_offset": 277,
      "end_offset": 282,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 29
    },
    {
      "token": "accountinstrumentsupdated",
      "start_offset": 284,
      "end_offset": 309,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 30
    },
    {
      "token": "minute",
      "start_offset": 311,
      "end_offset": 317,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 31
    },
    {
      "token": "1449384420",
      "start_offset": 319,
      "end_offset": 329,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 32
    }
  ]
}
```

The phrase "Production User:None:Username:None:LOG: publishing to bus "

```
 {
      "token": "production",
      "start_offset": 41,
      "end_offset": 51,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 7
    },
    {
      "token": "user:none:username:none:log",
      "start_offset": 52,
      "end_offset": 79,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 8
    },
    {
      "token": "publishing",
      "start_offset": 81,
      "end_offset": 91,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 9
    },
    {
      "token": "to",
      "start_offset": 92,
      "end_offset": 94,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 10
    },
    {
      "token": "bus",
      "start_offset": 95,
      "end_offset": 98,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 11
    }
```

So if you search "publishing to bus" the elasticsearch matches the above three token and return the document.

if you search "None:LOG: publishing to bus" "None:LOG:" doesn't match fully so it doesn't return the document.

you can try "User:None:Username:None:LOG: publishing to bus" to get the result.

Comment: The solution is to remplace character : for character _ or in the index indicate that the field is a non analyzed field.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems in Kibana with special character as : | and -. When kibana found that kind of character they save in different parts, not in the same field. For that is easy to find publishing to bus or None or log. The solution is that you must indicate to kibana that the field wil not be analyzed.

Comment: This isn't really an answer. all those characters exist in a single kibana field. Adding the raw json stored in kibana to the question to demonstrate that

Comment: You see as a simple fild but really kibana dont work in that way with that field. Try to pass that fild as not analyzed field.

Comment: What's stored and what's indexed are two different things.  As requested before, can you post the mapping?

Comment: Toy to do a replace of : for _ and you Will see that you can do the search.

Comment: @Deckard27 so if I replace (before inserting to kibana, with mutate or in my side before logging) all ':' to '_' then everything would work as expected?

Comment: I had the same problem and i replace all my "|" character for _ . I save in my index content of this type 0049|0012 kibana dosent found the full string and in a graph they draw only one part of the field. Then i replace all and my kibana start to work correctly. I supose that you have the same problem and the solution is the same.